# Error creating Azure Batch service

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I can't create an Azure Batch service. I keep getting error: "Please assign Contributor role to "MicrosoftAzureBatch" service principal through your Subscription's Access control (IAM) blade." even after adding it to my subscription Access control (IAM):

[image]

Comment: Has the SP been added on the subscription as a Contributor role? Additionally, have you considered using Batch Service pool allocation mode instead?

Answer (score 1):

We could get the detail steps about how to [Create a Batch account with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-account-create-portal) from azure officail document. It is odd that you can not create the service that if you have assigned the Contributor role.

If it is still not working for you, please have a try to create a **Batch account**. As the document mentioned that **user subscription mode** which is **no longer recommended for most scenarios**.

> When creating a Batch account, you should generally choose the **default Batch service mode**, in which pools are allocated behind the scenes in Azure-managed subscriptions. In the alternative **user subscription mode**, which is ***no longer recommended for most scenarios***, Batch VMs and other resources are created directly in your subscription when a pool is created. To create a Batch account in user subscription mode, you must also register your subscription with Azure Batch, and associate the account with an Azure Key Vault.

Answer (score 0):

I've already fixed the problem. It seems there was a permissions issue, and the error message was not clarifying at all, though. I've been able to create Azure Batch service logging into Azure portal with the subscription owner account, instead of mine's.

Comment: Hi, can you explain what exactly you have done to resolve the issue